# How can I append a string to a file name that is created with CHCSVWriter in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, csv

I'm using CHCSVWriter to write out a `csv` file, and that appears to be working, but I would like to append the UUID of the device to the filename, so I have something like, `myFile-0x1234-5678.csv`.  So far I have the following method,

```
- (void)exportUsers {
    NSLog(@"exportUsers method reached");

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    [request setEntity:[NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Account" inManagedObjectContext:_context]];
    NSError *error = nil;

    NSArray *objectsForExport = [_context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    NSArray *exportKeys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"username", @"pin", @"credit", @"email", @"lastLogin", @"rfid", @"phoneNumber", nil];

    NSMutableArray *csvObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[objectsForExport count]];
    for (NSManagedObject *object in objectsForExport) {
        NSMutableArray *anObjectArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[exportKeys count]];
        for (NSString *key in exportKeys) {
            id value = [object valueForKey:key];
            if (!value) {
                value = @"";
            }
            [anObjectArray addObject:[value description]];
        }
        [csvObjects addObject:anObjectArray];
    }
    NSLog(@"The output:%@",csvObjects);

    // need to figure out how to fetch the DeviceID and append it to the file name
    NSString *idfv = [[[UIDevice currentDevice] identifierForVendor] UUIDString];

    // write array to CSV file
//    CHCSVWriter *csvWriter=[[CHCSVWriter alloc]initForWritingToCSVFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"KegCop-users.csv"]];
    CHCSVWriter *csvWriter=[[CHCSVWriter alloc]initForWritingToCSVFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@",idfv]];
    [csvWriter writeLineOfFields:csvObjects];
    [csvWriter closeStream];

    [self uploadCSV];
}
```

Comment: Perhaps something like:  `[[CHCSVWriter alloc] initForWritingToCSVFile:[NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"KegCop-users-%@.csv",idfv]]]`?

Comment: I tried that but unfortunately the `stringByAppendingPathComponent` method only allows for one argument :'(

Comment: that did the trick, feel free to supply an answer, and I will accept it as the correct one.